# Newsoft Json deserialize into products Collection not working

Tags: c#, json, silverlight, collections, json-deserialization

I am creating a windows phone silver light 8 app.

I have a Json string and I am trying to convert it into a List of objects and each object is a object of a class classed "Product" and list is supposed to be products. ultimately I want it to convert into Observable collection so that I can bind that collection to my listbox in my windows Silverlight phone app.

**Here is my class**

```
public class Product
{
    public string _id { get; set; }
    public string code { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string imgAddress { get; set; }
    public int queryCount { get; set; }
}
```

**Here is code to deserialize the json**

```
var PDS = "{\"products\":[{\"_id\":\"58b2\",\"code\":\"59034\",\"name\":\"somename1\",\"imgAddress\":\"https://someimageurl/.../.jpg\",\"queryCount\":0},{\"_id\":\"58b3\",\"code\":\"59035\",\"name\":\"somename2\",\"imgAddress\":\"https://someimageurl2/.../.jpg\",\"queryCount\":1}]}";
var pds = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Product>>(PDS);
//PDS is actually very long string and the array products has a lot of objects but I am only writing 2 products here for simplicity.
```

**Here is my collection for binding**

```
public ObservableCollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
```

**ERRORS**
**>>** First I was getting parsing error so I escaped all quotes within the string like this  **\"**
**>>**But then it was only converting to a normal string like object but I want to convert to a collection of products of type "Product"

**>> Exception**

*Additional information: Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[PivotApp1.Product]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.
To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.*

*Path 'products', line 1, position 12.*

**Thanks in advance**

Comment: The code you've provided wouldn't even compile. Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can deserialize it this way (but you'll have somehow to reformat your JSON string):

from

```
var PDS = "{"products":[{"_id":"58b2","code":"59034","name":"somename1","imgAddress":"https://someimageurl/.../.jpg","queryCount":0},{"_id":"58b3","code":"59035","name":"somename2","imgAddress":"https://someimageurl2/.../.jpg","queryCount":1}]}";
//PDS is actually very long string and the array products has a lot of objects but I am only writing 2 products here for simplicity.
```

to

```
var PDS = "[{'_id':'58b2','code':'59034','name':'somename1','imgAddress':'https://someimageurl/.../.jpg','queryCount':0},{'_id':'58b3','code':'59035','name':'somename2','imgAddress':'https://someimageurl2/.../.jpg','queryCount':1}]";
//PDS is actually very long string and the array products has a lot of objects but I am only writing 2 products here for simplicity.
```

Then

```
var pds = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Product>>(PDS);
```

More infos --> [Deserialize a collection](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeCollection.htm)

No need of creating another class as suggested!

EDIT:
Actually you get this exception because your JSON string represents an object 'products' containing a list of 'Product' and this doesn't directly relate to your root class.

This is what your current JSON look like:

[image: Your current JSON string]

Your JSON string result should be something like that instead:

```
var PDS = "[{'_id':'58b2','code':'59034','name':'somename1','imgAddress':'https://someimageurl/.../.jpg','queryCount':0},{'_id':'58b3','code':'59035','name':'somename2','imgAddress':'https://someimageurl2/.../.jpg','queryCount':1}]";
```

Represented as following (notice the slight difference):

[image: Correct JSON string for List<Product> type]

Using this JSON string, it will work with no exception raised:

```
var pds = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Product>>(PDS);
```

Or, if you can't change the resulting JSON string in PDS, you can do what J. Tuc suggested (via a new "RootClass").

Comment: I already tried this method and it is giving me an exception, please see the post now , I just updated it with the exception.

Comment: just out of curiosity which method is better ? performance wise?

Comment: I did quick tests and it doen't change anything in terms of performance since your parsed string will be only a few bytes longer due to the extra 'products'. This has no performance impact. Just use the one that is more readable. In your case, I would go for changing the JSON string as I suggested so it REALLY matches your expected type, which is List<Product>. And, therefore, it's very easy to make the binding with your ObservableCollection<Product>.

Answer (score 2):

your JSON string had to be changed to get the code to compile:

```
var PDS = "{'products':[{'_id':'58b2','code':'59034','name':'somename1','imgAddress':'https://someimageurl/.../.jpg','queryCount':0},{'_id':'58b3','code':'59035','name':'somename2','imgAddress':'https://someimageurl2/.../.jpg','queryCount':1}]}";
```

You need another object with a collection of Product as a property called products in order to deserialize your JSON

This may not be the best solution but it works:

Create another class:

```
public class RootObject
{
    public List<Product> products;
}
```

use this code to deserialize your JSON:

```
var pds = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(PDS, typeof(RootObject));
```

if you are in control of your JSON string you might consider changing it to this (removing 'products' property and ending up with just an array of products in the JSON string):

```
var PDS = "[{'_id':'58b2','code':'59034','name':'somename1','imgAddress':'https://someimageurl/.../.jpg','queryCount':0},{'_id':'58b3','code':'59035','name':'somename2','imgAddress':'https://someimageurl2/.../.jpg','queryCount':1}]";
```

Then you might be able to use the solution proposed by TaiT's (deserializing directly to a List of Product) :

```
var pds = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Product>>(PDS);
```

Comment: it works but yes you are right it isn't the best solution it is slow. thanks a lot anyways :)